# Extract all elements from first non-numeric element

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to extract all the elements of a list from the first non-numeric element:

```
input = [u'12', u'23', u'hello', u'15', u'guys']
```

I want:

```
output = [u'hello', u'15', u'guys']
```

A non-pythonic version would be:

```
input_list = [u'12', u'23', u'hello', u'15', u'guys']

non_numeric_found=False
res = []
for e in input_list:
    if not non_numeric_found and e.isnumeric():
        continue
    non_numeric_found=True
    res.append(e)
```

Any suggestion for a better implementation of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
import itertools
input_list = [u'12', u'23', u'hello', u'15', u'guys']
res = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda s: s.isdigit(), input_list))
```

Comment: +1 for the itertools, just change it to: `list(itertools.dropwhile(str.isdigit, input_list))`

Comment: @eumiro That change would be a bad idea outside of codegolf. It's harder to read, doesn't allow non-str inputs, and most importantly, fails in this case because `s` is a `unicode`, not a `str`.

Comment: Thinking about it again I like the lambda as it's using duck typing.

Comment: isdigit and isnumeric have slightly different behaviour, e.g. unichr(188).isdigit() == False but .isnumeric() = True.  [188 is the 1/4 symbol.]  Probably the OP wanted isdigit anyway, but it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly longer but more explicit version without itertools:

```
it = iter(input_list)
res = [] # in case the list has no non-numeric elements

for e in it:
    if not e.isnumeric():
        res = [e] + list(it)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(ls):
 if (len(ls) == 0 or not ls[0].isnumeric()):
   return ls
 return f(ls[1:])

input = [u'12', u'23', u'hello', u'15', u'guys']
f(input)
>>> [u'hello', u'15', u'guys']
```